# Using svg sprites in wicket with use tag

Tags: java, svg, wicket

I am trying to use an svg sprite in wicket.
Usually it would look like this in HTML:

```
<svg>
   <use xlink:href="images/mysprite.svg#someSprite" />
</svg>
```

In wicket I would expect to use something like:

```
<use wicked:id="myResSprite"/>
```

or at least:

```
<img wicked:id="myResSprite"/>
```

because the first example gives an error that my resource can only be used with an IMG tag. But the img tag is also throwing an error because it does not like the # in the link
In my extension class of a WebPage I add an Image resource:

```
@Override
protected void onInitialize() {
    super.onInitialize();
    add(new Image("myResSprite", new ContextRelativeResource("images/mysprite.svg#someSprite")));
}
```

I tried it in various ways with or without the #-Sign but I could not get it to work.
All searches on google didn't find anything. All examples were svg but without sprites.

Does anyone have an example on how this could work?

Sidenote: I also tried using a `PackageResourceReference` but then I got an error Access Denied using the #-Sign link in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WebComponent` + `AttributeModifier` instead of `Image`.
This way you could produce any kind of HTML!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to wicket but I assume that I then get the error that I am not using the image anywhere i added in the initialize. As I tried to hardcode the tags but then go that error.

Comment: Please update the question with your latest code, both Java and HTML.